# AMPScript: IndexOf() Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to populate an email address within the BCC field, if and only if the company name has specific text in it. I believe the answer is [IndexOf()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/indexof/), but it doesn't seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong here? Do I not need to set the variable? Would love to find the shortest possible code for this.

```
%%[

  Var @co 
  Set @co = "Red Company" 

  IF IndexOf(@AgentName,@co) > 0 THEN 

]%%

"email@email.com"

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

### Example of the values in the field are things like:

**AgentName**
Red Company
Red Company, Inc.
Red Company-Agent123
Green Company
Red-Green Company
The Hide Away
Cabin in the Woods, LLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@AgentName` should contain a string so that `@co` can evaluate the character position from that particular string.

```
%%[

  Var @co, @AgentName
  Set @co = "Red Company" 
  Set @AgentName = "Red Company-Agent123" /*if AgentName is field in DE then fetch the value from DE*/
  IF IndexOf(@AgentName,@co) > 0 THEN 

]%%

"email@email.com"

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Does it accept  Set @AgentName = %%AgentName%% ? I would want it to evaluate whatever is in that row for the field, since the values won't be static.

Comment: you cannot write inline ampscript code inside the block code, you can do something like this `@AgentName = AgentName`. I suppose this is an email so you will be selecting a DE, AgentName will fetch the value automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the attributes from the sending Data Extension or List, then you can use the [**AttributeValue()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/) function:

```
 %%[

  Var @co, @AgentName
  Set @co = AttributeValue("co")
  Set @AgentName = AttributeValue("AgentName")

  IF not empty(@co) and not empty(@agentName) and IndexOf(@AgentName,@co) > 0 THEN 

   output(concat("<br>Email address: ", @AgentName,"@email.com"))

  ENDIF

 ]%%
```

or if you want to break out of the AMPScript block:

```
 %%[

  Var @co, @AgentName
  Set @co = AttributeValue("co")
  Set @AgentName = AttributeValue("AgentName")

  IF not empty(@co) and not empty(@agentName) and IndexOf(@AgentName,@co) > 0 THEN 

 ]%%

   %%=concat("<br>Email address: ", @AgentName,"@email.com")=%%

 %%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

AttributeValue() will give you an opportunity to ensure the value exists using the [**empty()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/empty/) function.

Comment: That does look interesting. I won't be able to use it for this solution, though, because the BCC is limiting me to 250 characters. Our BCC already has two other emails for archiving/agent notice purposes, but I'll keep this in mind for future things!